# pandas how to eliminate duplicate rows before they occur

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe consisting of the State name and City Name. However, the City names are not simply Pittsburg, Philadelphia, etc. The city name may contain what I call prestige names. Here is a small sample

```
State            RegionName
Pennsylvania     California (California Uni...
Pennsylvania     Carlisle (Dickinson College)
Pennsylvania     Cecil B. Moore, Philadelphia, also...
...
Pennsylvania     University City, Philadelphia (Drexel Universi...
```

I need to clean up this data by removing the parenthetical information and such. But my question is this. Both Cecil B. Moore and University City are parts of Philadelphia. If I rename these values the I have two rows of Pennsylvania Philadelphia in my data set. I don't want that.

So from a data science perspective, is it acceptable for me to simply delete one of these rows and rename the RegionName value in the other? Or is there some way, in pandas, to "combine" these rows after cleanup and renaming.

This data will eventually be married to housing values by state and region name (city).

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to keep the sub-city regions as well as the city name, or just the city name?  If you want to keep just the city name, you can remove duplicates after ingestion.

Comment: @James If I understand you correctly, both of those cities will be renamed to Philadelphia and all other information will be cleansed from the data. So then you are saying that drop_duplicates() will remove one of these leaving the other?

Comment: yes.  if you rows 1, 3, and 7 have Pennsylvania, Philadelphia for State, RegionName, then using `drop_duplicates()` will remove rows 3 and 7.  This is assuming there are no other columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just ingest all of the row, then use `.drop_duplicates()` to remove the duplicate rows from the data frame.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Much appreciated